# Selecting a row of DataGridView programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my form application, there is a (`buttonNEW`) that selects `NewIndexRow` of `DataGridView` and I want to change index of datagridview with this button.

```
private void buttonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index!=dataGridView.NewRowIndex)
        {
            dataGridView.ClearSelection();
            dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.NewRowIndex].Selected = true;
            label1.Text = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index.ToString();

        }
    }
```

But after clicking the button the index of `DataGridView` does not change.
What is the problem?

Comment: are you sure that NewRowIndex has a value ?

Comment: NewRowIndex is Empty row .I want to user click buttonNEW and select last row for entering data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work :-

```
int numofRows = dataGridView.rows.count;

dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[numofRows - 1].Cells[0];
```

Or I think you could also do this :-

```
dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.NewRowIndex].Cells[0];
```

Comment: I have tried your method and it works fine for me,does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Linc:

```
private void buttonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

     dataGridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Last().Selected = true;

   }
```